# How to upload multiple images and single text from a form

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form where i have to upload multiple images but my it inserts only one input form value into the database.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file_upload']['name']); $i++){
      $filetmp  = $_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'][$i];
      $filename = $_FILES['file_upload']['name'][$i];
      $filetype = $_FILES['file_upload']['type'][$i];
      $filepath = "../images/".$filename;
      move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath);

    $title        = $_POST['title'];
    $location     = $_POST['location'];
    $price        = $_POST['price'];
    $type         = $_POST['type'];
    $str = '0123456789qazxswedcvfrbgtnhymjuklio';
    $str = str_shuffle($str);
    $str = substr($str, 0, 10); 

    $sql  = "INSERT INTO pictures (";
    $sql .= "photograph_id, image, title, location, price, type";
    $sql .= ") VALUES ('";
    $sql .= $str ."', '";   
    $sql .= $filename ."', '";  
    $sql .= $title ."', '";
    $sql .= $location ."', '";  
    $sql .= $price ."', '"; 
    $sql .= $type ."')";
    $result = $database->query($sql);
        if($result){
        $session->message('<div class="btn bg-success">Picture uploaded sucessfully.</div>');
        redirect_to('picture_upload.php');
        }
}
  }
?>
```

Please note: whenever i select ,multiple images and insert into the database, my query inserts one image and the input details without inserting the rest of the images... i am a bit confused about my loop.

```
<form action="picture_upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="file_upload" type="hidden" name="file_upload" class="col-sm-3 control-label" >Upload Image:</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo $max_file_size; ?>" />
    <input type="file" id="file_upload" name="file_upload[]" multiple="multiple" required class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label" >Title:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" required id="title" onchange="trim(this)" class="form-control" name="title" />
           </div>
       </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="location" class="col-sm-2 control-label" >Location:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" required id="location" onchange="trim(this)" class="form-control" name="location" />
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="price" class="col-sm-2 control-label" >Price:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" required id="price" onchange="trim(this)" class="form-control" name="price" />
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <select name="type" class="form-control col-sm-3 custom-select">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Rent">For Rent</option>
        <option value="Sale">For Sale</option>
        </select>
       </div>  
    <div class="form-group">
       <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-push-2">
           <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Upload</button>
           </div>
       </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Because you exit the loop with a redirdect - so your loop will always run just once

Answer (score 0):

Because of

```
if($result){
    $session->message('<div class="btn bg-success">Picture uploaded sucessfully.</div>');
    redirect_to('picture_upload.php');
    }
```

After first insertion if insert successfully you redirect page. When you redirect then the script terminate execution.

Answer (score 0):

As [B001ᛦ pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55918650/how-to-upload-multiple-images-and-single-text-from-a-form/55920229#comment98491511_55918650), my original code was existing the loop with a redirect. This meant that the loop was only running once.

The following revision of the code removes the redirect inside the loop, replacing it with a simple echo of a string indicating success.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file_upload']['name']); $i++){
      $filetmp  = $_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'][$i];
      $filename = $_FILES['file_upload']['name'][$i];
      $filetype = $_FILES['file_upload']['type'][$i];
      $filepath = "../images/".$filename;
      move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath);

    $title        = $_POST['title'];
    $location     = $_POST['location'];
    $price        = $_POST['price'];
    $type         = $_POST['type'];
    $str = '0123456789qazxswedcvfrbgtnhymjuklio';
    $str = str_shuffle($str);
    $str = substr($str, 0, 10); 

    $sql  = "INSERT INTO pictures (";
    $sql .= "photograph_id, image, title, location, price, type";
    $sql .= ") VALUES ('";
    $sql .= $str ."', '";   
    $sql .= $filename ."', '";  
    $sql .= $title ."', '";
    $sql .= $location ."', '";  
    $sql .= $price ."', '"; 
    $sql .= $type ."')";
    $result = $database->query($sql);
        if($result){
        echo "success";
        }
}
  }
?>
```